# Vista: How to prevent an extended partition from converting to EISA?

Tags: partitioning, windows-vista, recovery-partition

So I tried to create an extended partition with two logical drives on an Acer Vista laptop which has two EISA recovery partitions. After reboot I see the extended partition has been replaced with a partition called *EISA configuration* and the two new drives are gone.

Steps:

- EISA 13GB | C 282GB | EISA 3GB : shrink C
- EISA 13GB | C 64GB | free 218BG | EISA 3GB : create two drives D/E
- EISA | C 64GB | D 64GB | E 154GB | EISA (all primary except D/E which are in extended part)
- EISA 13GB | C 64GB | EISA 218GB | EISA 3GB : after reboot, a 3rd EISA part shows up?

I used the MiniTool Partition Wizard to change the new EISA partition back into the logical drives, but on the next reboot the change is reverted and the drives are gone again.

How to keep the system from reclaiming the extended partition to EISA? Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**

I've read the suggested solutions (remove the OEM partitions), but at the moment I want to keep the OEM recovery feature. I've managed to prevent the disk space from being converted to EISA by assigning it a *primary* partition like this:

- EISA 13GB | C 64GB | D 218GB | EISA 3GB (all primary)

But I'm interested in a solution that helps me keep the extended partition with several logical drives, as shown above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["EISA Configuration" partition](https://superuser.com/questions/59373/eisa-configuration-partition)

Comment: http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/190511en

Comment: Thanks, I've read that before. I don't want to remove the recovery partitions, I'm just looking for a way to prevent the extended one being converted to EISA?

Comment: OEM Recovery partitions are not helpful.